# How to add the filter or ScaleExtent in d3 v4 in Timeline with Zoom functionality

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming

I am working on timeline in d3 version 4. So i have created a **SVG** and added the **axis** and **zoom** on that SVG as below.

```
var timeLineSVG = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 300)
                .attr("height", 300);
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([Date.parse("April 1, 2017"), Date.parse("April 30, 2017")])
            .range([0, 300]);

var xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale);

var timeLineZoom = d3.zoom(xScale)
                    .on("zoom", onTimeLineZoom);

var timeLineGraphics = timeLineSVG.append("g")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(0,40)")
                                .call(xAxis);
timeLineSVG.call(timeLineZoom);

function onTimeLineZoom(event) {
    var tempScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
    timeLineGraphics.call(xAxis.scale(tempScale));
}
```

The **domain** and **range** for the scale is going to change based on the data. So I want to **allow zoom only till day level not beyond the day level**.

Here is the [small example what I have done.](http://jsbin.com/ketacigeta/1/edit?js,output)

We can use the scaleextent property on the zoom instance but what is the value and how can we calculate with out hard coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scaleExtend([minScaleFactor, maxScaleFactor])` to control it.
Example:  `d3.zoom().scaleExtend([0.5, 10])`